# VRP Multiple deliveries to one order, ArcGIS network analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.5, vehicle-routing-problem

I am working on a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP), with network analyst in ArcGIS 10.5.1, for a number of depots and orders in the city Berlin (Germany). From the distribution centres (depots) trucks will supply supermarkets (orders).

The supermarkets have a specific number of tons they need to get delivered. This number is present in the attribute table. The number of tons differs between 11 and 106. The trucks have a capacity of 30 tons, which means that some supermarkets can be supply at once, but others need several truck loads.

My problem is that only supermarkets that ask for less than 30 tons are reached. All the supermarkets which require more than one delivery (more than 30 tons) are skipped by the trucks.
I already applied the route renewals to the trucks, so they are refilled after suppling a supermarket.

Does somebody know how I can let the truck also deliver to the supermarkets, which require more than 30 tons of goods?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with VRP solving in ArcGIS, but you could try splitting a single order for a supermarket into multiple orders of say 5 tons each, each with the same location.

The solver should then group them logically.